# Transition on light/dark mode

Tags: javascript, html, css, light

I did the code for dark/light mode this way, using Javascript and CSS. but I can't find anywhere a way to add a transition on changing the light/dark modes.

CSS

```
 :root {
    --primary-bg-color: #F5F5F5;
    --secondary-bg-color: #FFFF;
    --primary-text-color: #2B283A;
    --secondary-text-color: #4A4E74;
}

    .dark-theme {
    --primary-bg-color: #3A69D2;
    --secondary-bg-color: #1F2937;
    --primary-text-color: #FFFF;
    --secondary-text-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

JS

```
icon.onclick = function() {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme")
    if(document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")){
        icon.src = "sun.png"
    }else {
        icon.src = "moon.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding a mutation handler or onclick function to make this work.

Comment: Are you trying to have a transition on changing the img src of some sort?

Comment: what do you mean by transition, explain in detail (step-by-step or like a story) what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the element by its id and then set its image source

```
icon.onclick = function() {
    document.body.classList.toggle("dark-theme")
    if(document.body.classList.contains("dark-theme")){
        document.getElementById("myIcon").src = "sun.png";
    }else {
        document.getElementById("myIcon").src = "moon.png";
    }
}
```

Example: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_img_src2